# Embed Jetty in Android build for testing

Tags: android, gradle, jetty

I want to embed Jetty in my Android build so I can run some functional tests from within our corporate firewall. (We currently have a few tests that need to confirm we can make regular http connections from the device.) I have been tinkering with embedding Jetty in my build.gradle as a pre-req task to running the tests but I keep hitting a brick wall. The [Gradle Jetty plugin is deprecated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html) in favor of [the Gretty plugin](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty). I'm looking at the Gretty plugin but it's not straight forward enough where it explains how to simply bring up an instance of Jetty without defining a fun blown war project. Has anyone tried this before? I just want to start a jetty with a hello world page prior to running my instrumentation tests.

Comment: I don't get, what are you trying to check/test during the build? Can you give requirements without implementation?

Comment: In our Android app we intercept certain web requests from a web view in the main activity. Simple requirements are: GIVEN our webview running in our activity WHEN aol.com is requested THEN the request will actually go to aol.com. I simply want to replace aol.com with localhost for instrumentation testing and have Gradle spawn a web server to respond on localhost.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver?